# HTML image pop up while hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want those images to be visible when i hover them over the text. But according to this it works but it selects the first one only as there is same id for every images. Does anyone knows to fix this problem.Thanks in advance. New to web page dev. So please explain in details. Thanks.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>jQuery UI Selectable - Default functionality</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

        <script type = "text/javascript" src = "js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type = "text/javascript" src = "js/jquery_ui.js"></script>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">

        <style>
            #feedback { font-size: 1.4em; }
            #selectable .ui-selecting { background: #FECA40; }
            #selectable .ui-selected { background: #F39814; color: white; }
            #selectable { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 20%; }
            #selectable li { margin: 3px; padding: 0.4em; font-size: 1.4em; height: 18px; }

            img
            {
                position:absolute;
                left:250px;
                display:none;
            }
        </style>

        <script>        
            $(function() {
                $( "#selectable" ).selectable();
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>

        <table id="myTable">
            <td>
                <tr>
                    <ol id="selectable" onmouseover="show(next,true)" onmouseout="show(next,false)">
                        <li>Item 1 <img src="next.jpg" id="next1"></li>
                        <li>Item 2 <img src="next.jpg" id="next2"></li>
                        <li>Item 3 <img src="next.jpg" id="next3"></li>
                        <li>Item 4 <img src="next.jpg" id="next4"></li>
                        <li>Item 5 <img src="next.jpg" id="next5"></li>
                    </ol>
                </tr>
            </td>
        </table>

        <script type = "text/javascript"> 
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#selectable').fadeIn('very slow');
            });
        </script>

        <script language="javascript">
        //function to display the immage
            function show(id,disp) {
                if (disp == true) {
                    id.style.display = "block";
                }

                if (disp == false) {
                    id.style.display = "none";
                }
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Looks to me like you should use CSS instead: `li:hover img { display: block;}`. No need to use JavaScript at all.

Comment: that sounds great. Thanks alot for replying. Ill try this out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

html code:

```
<a href="#">some text here..<img src="image url" /></a>
```

css code:

```
a img { display:none; }
a:hover img { display:block; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#selectable li").mouseover(function(){
    $(this).next().show();
});

$("#selectable li").mouseout(function(){
    $(this).next().hide();
});
```

you can try this

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need any fade-in effect, use CSS `#selectable li:hover img { display: block; }`

If you do need effects, use this:

```
$("#selectable li" ).hover(
    function() {
       $(this).find("img").fadeIn(1000);
    }, function() {
       $(this).find("img").fadeOut(1000);
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually need the Selectable plugin to do this - you can do this using the [jQuery hover function](http://api.jquery.com/hover/).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#selectable li').hover(function(){
        $(this).find('img').toggle();
    });
});
```

The function is saying that if you hover over the li element in #selectable, it will show, and then will do the reverse when you move away from that element.

[Fiddle for reference](http://fiddle.jshell.net/Fhma9/)